# How to show calculated history in php

Tags: php

I'm creating a calculator using PHP and would like to show what has been calculated (list the calculated history) but I have no idea how to store and display the information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Basic PHP Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            //var_export($_POST);
            //echo "<br>";
            $buttons=[1,3,5,'+',7,9,0,'/','C','='];
            $pressed='';
            if(isset($_POST['pressed']) && in_array($_POST['pressed'],$buttons)){
                $pressed=$_POST['pressed'];
            }
            $stored='';
            if(isset($_POST['stored']) && preg_match('~^(?:[\d.]+[*/+-]?)+$~',$_POST['stored'],$out)){
                $stored=$out[0];    
            }
            $display=$stored.$pressed;
            //echo "$pressed & $stored & $display<br>";
            if($pressed=='C'){
                $display='';
            }elseif($pressed=='=' && preg_match('~^\d*\.?\d+(?:[*/+-]\d*\.?\d+)*$~',$stored)){
                $display.=eval("return $stored;");
            }

            echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
            echo "<table style=\"width:300px;border:solid thick black;\">";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=\"4\">$display</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            foreach(array_chunk($buttons,4) as $chunk){
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach($chunk as $button){
                    echo "<td",(sizeof($chunk)!=4?" colspan=\"4\"":""),"><button name=\"pressed\" value=\"$button\">$button</button></td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"stored\" value=\"$display\">";
            echo "</form>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected to get a list of what has been calculated like:

**Calculate history:**

```
2+2=4
3+4=7
```

Answer (score 0):

Append results in `SESSION` only when `isequalto(=)` button pressed:

```
session_start();
elseif($pressed=='=' && preg_match('~^\d*\.?\d+(?:[*/+-]\d*\.?\d+)*$~',$stored)){
 $display.=eval("return $stored;"); 
 $_SESSION["list"].=$display."<br>";
}
```

And finally display the history:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["list"];?>
```